# CSS - SearchBox overlapping divs' padding

Tags: html, css, input, padding, overlapping

I had this problem quite a few times and never were able to solve it.

I basically just have a div with 20px padding and would like to fit the searchbox 100% relative to the divs' possible width (including the padding). But the searchbox keeps overlapping the padding from the div. Can anybody help me there?

```
<div class='content'>
        <form id='submit' action='' method=''>
            <input type='text' autofocus='on' placeholder='Search with DuckDuckGo' autocomplete='off' id='searchBox'>
        </form>

        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

```
.content { # This is the main div!
   background-color: rgba(240,240,240, 1);
   padding: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 25%;
   width: 40%;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px #101010;
}

#searchBox { # This here is the search box that keeps overlapping the padding from the content div...
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   border: 1px rgba(10,10,10, 0.2) solid;
   #border: none;
   color: rgba(10,10,10, 0.5);
   font-family: 'Roboto', 'Tahoma', 'sans-serif';
}
```

Here is a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Ljgr8/) example to visualize it a little bit better.

Comment: just make width 90% in #searchbox

Comment: see this : https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Ljgr8/2/

Comment: @Dev-One your solution removes the padding from #searchbox which may not be desired i guess

Comment: updated: https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Ljgr8/4/   Add a padding: 5px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `padding` property for `#searchBox` and explicitly set the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` property to 10px (Which will remove left and right padding).

```
#searchBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px rgba(10,10,10, 0.2) solid;
    color: rgba(10,10,10, 0.5);
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Tahoma', 'sans-serif';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Ljgr8/1/

An alternative solution would be to reduce the width of `#searchBox` to 90% width, as shown in this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Ljgr8/3/

Comment: This pretty much solves the problem. But is it possible to add left and right padding without making the searchbox overlap the padding from the div?

Comment: @Dean - yes you could also reduce the width to 90%, I've updated my answer to reflect this also.